# solution to Riccati differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I recently bumped into the following differential equation
$$
zA'(z)=(a_2 z+b_2)A^2(z)+(a_1 z+b_1)A(z)+a_0 z+b_0
$$
In my case the terms $a_i$ and $b_i$ are negative real constants, except for $b_1>0$.
Dividing through by $z$ the above becomes a Riccati equation, but this didn't help me in getting a solution. Any suggestion?_______